# Bokeh server statistics

Tags: python, server, bokeh, network-traffic

I have created an application that runs on a Bokeh server and can be accessed by others in a network.

How can I obtain information on the incoming traffic?

In particular, over an observed period of time (e.g one day) how can I find out the following:

1. Which clients have accessed my server?
2. How many interactions has a particular client had with my server (i.e. clicks in the application)
3. How long did a particular client stay connected with the server

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing currently built-in. Some of that information is emitted (possibly implicitly) in the console logs, which you could parse. I've considered that something like an 'admin' panel could be useful, for some time, but there are lots of open questions (e.g. about auth and access) and very little perceived demand or comment, so it has never been prioritized. Please feel free to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss details (and especially if you are interested to collaborate on implementing it).